# QuickFIX setting PreviouslyReported field is ignored?

Tags: quickfix

I'm using QuickFIX C++ engine in my project.

I send a TradeCaptureReport message to a counter party. There's a field named PreviouslyReported in this message.

I set this value to N in the message but when I check the message that was sent, I see that it is set to Y in the resulting message.

Does QuickFIX set this field itself ignoring the value that I set?

```
message.set(FIX::PreviouslyReported(FIX::PreviouslyReported_NO));
```

Regards

Comment: What does the data dictionary say about the PreviouslyReported field in the TradeCaptureReport. It could specify a default?

Answer (score 0):

It's defined as a `boolean`, so you must use instead :

```
message.set(FIX::PreviouslyReported(false));
```